# export KML file from my google map android

Tags: android, kml

I drawed some lines and polygon on google map and I want to export this map as kml file , How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I put everything into a class while I'm parsing the kml coming in.  I use the same class from my 1st app in this 2nd app.  Just extended the original class.  It's pretty cool to me to have 100% reuse of a class from another app and use the super opcode.

Anyways.  Basically its a list of polyline Options and a list of marker options.

super.get_po which is the polylines option
super.get_mo which is the marker options

Then I just serialize that class back out when I'm writing kml.  My golf app depends on the order of markers and lines.  For each hole It goes marker, line, marker and I use the same style as http://maps.google.com where each element has it's own style.

from [my golf app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.mymulliganstroker) which has a whopping earth shattering two downloads me and probably my wifes phone.

```
    @Override
public void saveGolfMap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileOutputStream fileos = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        fileos = new FileOutputStream(super.get_pathstring());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Log.e("FileNotFoundException", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // serialize the file();
    try {

        xmlSerializer = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newSerializer();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        xmlSerializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
        xmlSerializer.startDocument(null, null);
        xmlSerializer.setFeature(
                "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output",
                true);
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "kml");
        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "xmlns",
                "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2");
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Document");

        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
        xmlSerializer.text("todo put the name here");
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");

        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "description");
        xmlSerializer.cdsect("todo put the description here");
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "description");

        // spin through the marker options and create a style section for
        // each two
        // markers create three style sections
        // <Style id="style1">
        // <IconStyle>
        // <Icon>
        // <href>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/golfer.png</href>
        // </Icon>
        // </IconStyle>
        // </Style>
        // <Style id="style2">
        // <IconStyle>
        // <Icon>
        // <href>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/flag.png</href>
        // </Icon>
        // </IconStyle>
        // </Style>
        // <Style id="style3">
        // <LineStyle>
        // <color>73FF0000</color>
        // <width>3</width>
        // </LineStyle>
        // </Style>
        setInt();
        int y = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < mosize; k++) {
            y += 1;
            if (k % 2 == 0) {
                // write out the tee marker style
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Style");
                xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "id",
                        "style" + Integer.toString(y));
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "IconStyle");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Icon");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "href");
                xmlSerializer
                        .text("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/golfer.png");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "href");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Icon");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "IconStyle");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Style");

                // write out the polyline style
                y += 1;
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Style");
                xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "id",
                        "style" + Integer.toString(y));
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "LineStyle");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "color");
                xmlSerializer.text("73FF0000");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "color");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "width");
                xmlSerializer.text("10");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "width");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "LineStyle");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Style");

            } else {
                // write out the cup marker style
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Style");
                xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "id",
                        "style" + Integer.toString(y));
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "IconStyle");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Icon");
                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "href");
                xmlSerializer
                        .text("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/flag.png");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "href");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Icon");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "IconStyle");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Style");

            }
        }

        // write placemark for tee
        // write poly lines
        // write placemark for cup
        // <Placemark>
        // <name>Tee Hole 1</name>
        // <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        // <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
        // <Point>
        // <coordinates>-xx.999999,xx.999999,0.000000</coordinates>
        // </Point>
        // </Placemark>

        y = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < mosize; k++) {
            y += 1;
            // write out the tee or cup PlaceMark
            mo = super.get_mo().get(k);
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Placemark");
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
            xmlSerializer.text(mo.getTitle());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "description");
            xmlSerializer.cdsect("");
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "description");
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "styleUrl");
            xmlSerializer.text("#style" + Integer.toString(y));
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "styleUrl");
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Point");
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "coordinates");
            ll = mo.getPosition();

            xmlSerializer.text(Double.toString(ll.longitude) + ","
                    + Double.toString(ll.latitude) + ",0.000000");
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "coordinates");
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Point");
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Placemark");

            // write out the polyline options
            // <Placemark>
            // <name>Hole One</name>
            // <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
            // <styleUrl>#style3</styleUrl>
            // <LineString>
            // <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            // <coordinates>
            // -xx.999999,xx.999999,0.000000
            // -xx.999999,xx.999999,0.000000
            // -xx.999999,xx.999999,0.000000
            // -xx.9999999,xx.999999,0.000000
            // -xx.9999999,xx.999999,0.000000
            // </coordinates>
            // </LineString>
            // </Placemark>if (hole > 0){
            if (k % 2 == 0) {
                int z = k / 2;
                if (z < posize) {
                    y += 1;
                    po = this.get_po().get(z);
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Placemark");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "description");
                    xmlSerializer.cdsect("");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "description");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "styleUrl");
                    xmlSerializer.text("#style" + Integer.toString(y));
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "styleUrl");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "LineString");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "tessellate");
                    xmlSerializer.text("1");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "tessellate");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "coordinates");
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    for (LatLng ll3 : po.getPoints()) {
                        sb.append(Double.toString(ll3.longitude));
                        sb.append(",");
                        sb.append(Double.toString(ll3.latitude));
                        sb.append(",0.000000\n");
                    }
                    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
                    String s = sb.toString();
                    xmlSerializer.text(s);
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "coordinates");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "LineString");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Placemark");
                }
            }
        }

        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Document");
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "kml");
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();
        xmlSerializer.flush();
        fileos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Log.e("Exception", "Exception occured in wroting");
    }

}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Just a note if you don't close a tag correctly the xmlserializer will complain with exception.